# What happens when we don't specify <meta charset="utf-8">?

Tags: html

What happens when we don't specify `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the HEAD of the HTML document?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Whether such a `meta` tag is present or not, browsers and user agents will first look at the HTTP headers to find encoding information there. Actually, they will even before that honor user settings and do BOM sniffing, as described in section 8.2.2.1 [Determining the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) in HTML5 CR – which is in this issue a description of the reality rather than just proposed norm.

So the answer is really “it depends”. In many cases, the `meta` tag is ignored, so omitting it has no effect, except perhaps in situations where the HTML document is saved locally (so that HTTP headers are lost). In many other cases, it is not ignored, but if it is omitted, browsers will infer the correct encoding anyway. And in some cases, where the tag happens to be the only thing that makes the browser use the right encoding, omitting it will cause wrong interpretation of data, typically so that bytes are interpreted in windows-1252 encoding. What this matters depends on the actual content.

Comment: Could you give an example where omitting would make a difference?

Answer (score 17):

> What happens when we don't specify `<meta charset="utf-8">` ? in the HEAD of the HTML document?

The user agent looks for the Content-Type response HTTP header sent from the server:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

And if the Content-Type header doesn't specify a `charset` the depending on the User Agent different things might happen. Some user agents might try to use heuristics to *guess* the correct charset by analyzing some of the bytes from the response stream looking for known encodings. And if this fails you might end up with a couple of question marks or weird symbols in your web page at the place where you used characters outside of the ASCII range.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading, since the HTTP header is always examined first.

Answer (score 5):

for characters such as:
`↑→↓←`

they would show as:
`â†‘â†’â†“â†`

unless you use the UTF-8 format:
`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Came here to say this. This goes for MS Word formatted text pasted into HTML as well. `<meta charset="utf-8">` is the difference between seeing `“…”` vs seeing `â€œâ€¦â€`